# What renders Create React App html template during build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Create React App includes a `public/index.html` which contains several strings that are being replaced by a templating engine.

`<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`

My question is where in the CRA webpack config file or build script is `%PUBLIC_URL%` being replaced with the other value? I have seen where the CRA uses the html-webpack-plugin, but this appears to use the default lodash templating engine, which uses different syntaxt to demark what gets replaced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement is done by the `InterpolateHtmlPlugin`.

Here is the corresponding line in the webpack config: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L655

And here is the source for InterpolateHtmlPlugin: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin.js

Comment: it would be great if the links are actually permalink instead of pointing to main branch.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the config/env.js file PUBLIC_URL is set:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/a10223d418e4093856bd225e6e4be6e12ac8ae4e/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js#L71

Then inside config/webpack.config.js is where getClientEnvironment(publicUrl) is called:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/a10223d418e4093856bd225e6e4be6e12ac8ae4e/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L79

Comment: I see where it is getting publicUrl on line 79 in webpack.config.js

However, I cannot locate what is subsitituting ```%PUBLIC_URL%``` with the value of ```publicUrl``` in the copy of index.html in the build folder. My initial instinct is that is happening due to Line 576 of the webpack config file. However, ```%PUBLIC_URL%``` is not in the format used by lodash templating, so I dont think that is it.